# p:dataExporter throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/lowagie/text/phrase

Tags: jsf, primefaces, itext

I tried to use the data exporter control of PrimeFaces 3.2. Following is the code:

```html
<p:commandLink value="export" ajax="false">
    <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="dtable" fileName="myfile" />  
</p:commandLink>
<p:datatable id="dtable" .../>
```

When I click on export link, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/lowagie/text/phrase
```

I downloaded itext jar 5.2.1 and included it in my application, still I get the same error.
How do I solve it?

Comment: This question is strange. iText is used for exporting PDF files, but you're actually trying to export an XLS file. Try to be more careful with providing the relevant code snippets.

Comment: well i tried to export pdf too but still the same

Comment: data exporter is not working for me. I am using tab view I am submitting values to database in one tab and viewing the values on other tab. I want to download it as excel. I am not able to do this . have been struggling for two days for this small issue.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try iText 2.1.7 not 5.2.1.
http://olex.openlogic.com/packages/itext/2.1.7

I think there are licence conflicts. So primefaces uses 2.1.7

For Excel Export you need Apache POI.
Try 3.7: http://archive.apache.org/dist/poi/release/bin/

**Edit**

(you need only the `poi-3.7*.jar` and `poi-ooxml-3.7*.jar`)

Comment: should i download source or binary?

Comment: it worked for pdf only, not for excel :( what should i do for xls?

Answer (score 0):

Go to netbeans, on your project dependency add a new dependency. Type Query type  iText 2.1.7  then choose com.lowagie:itext. you should be able to download with dpf
:D

Answer (score 0):

Copy this code to your `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime.3_7_1</groupId> 
    <artifactId>com.lowagie.text</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

And this is what the XHTML should be:

```
<h:commandLink>
        <img src="/img/icones/excel.png"/>
        <p:dataExporter type="xlsx" target="tbl" fileName="#{relatorioController.relatorio.nome}" />
</h:commandLink>

<p:spacer width="10"/>

<h:commandLink>
        <img src="/img/icones/pdf.png"/>
        <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="tbl" fileName="#{relatorioController.relatorio.nome}"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is an [English-only site](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676). Thus, all answers must be written in English. Please keep this in mind for future posts.

Answer (score -1):

Just add the following dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score -3):

I was having the same problem, but when i downloaded the jars it  doesn't worked.
Then I noticed I was using `<p:commandLink>`, the correct is to use `<h:commandLink>` for some reason `<p:commandLink>` won't work.

Don't use:

`<p:commandLink >
     <p:graphicImage value="images/excel.png" width="48"/>
     <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="table" fileName="tablexls" encoding="UTF-8" />
 </p:commandLink>`

instead use:

`<h:commandLink >
     <p:graphicImage value="images/custom/excel.png" width="48"/>
     <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="table" fileName="tablexls" encoding="UTF-8" />
 </h:commandLink>`

Comment: Find the basic difference between `h:commandLink` and `p:commandLink`! That is most likely the cause of it not working **for you**.... You can already see the difference if you look at the commandLink in the question (which DOES work btw) But I seriously doubt just changing an h: to p: commandLink resolves a classNotFound Error... So in all, your answer is totally **not** applicable to the question...

Comment: It was the reason why wasn't working for me. I posted this answer because i tried the best answer here and it still didn't worked, it only worked when i changed the commandLinks. That's why my answer is aplicable to the question, because he WAS using `<p:commandLink>` and AFTER I tried the best answer I was still having this issue and corrected with my answer.