# p:dataExporter NOT working

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to write a simple pdf export functionality using primefaces p:dataExporter. My Code is as below

my development environment is JSF-2.0, Primefaces-3.4.2, Eclips- JUNO, GlassFish

xhtml page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    >
<h:head>
    <title>Pdf Export</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<h:form id="myForm" >
    <p:dataTable id="tableId" var="car" value="#{tableBean.carsSmall}">
        <p:column headerText="Model">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.model}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Year">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>

        <h:commandLink ajax="false" >  
            <p:graphicImage library="images" name="pdf.png" width="40" height="40" />  
            <p:dataExporter target="tableId" type="pdf" fileName="car"></p:dataExporter>
        </h:commandLink>

</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

my dataTable is populated correctly there is no issue there but when I click for Export nothing happens. Console also doesn't give any message. I have kept iTextpdf-5.4.0.jar and poi-3.2-FINAL.jar in my webapp library. Do I need to do anything else here? Please give me some idea what I am missing?

**EDIT-1**

I tried using iTextpdd-2.1.7 as suggested in the comment below but still  the same problem exist and I am not able to export to pdf.

When I click export the console gives me warning message as below. Is this warning message creating any problem in the export

```
WARNING: PWC4011: Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context 
/{project name}, because request parameters have already been read, or 
ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called
```

**EDIT-2**

Today I tried the same code in RAD-Wehsphere/iText 2.1.7 and Export is working fine in that environment. I am able to export dataTable in the pdf file. There must be something that is missing in the Eclips- JUNO, GlassFish environment.

TIA

Comment: You try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899368/data-exporter-of-primefaces-not-working

Comment: Could you try to delete headerText of `p:column`'s and use `f:facet name="header"` instead.

Comment: tried using f:facet but by doing it doesn't built the data table and also export problem remains

Comment: As to PWC4011: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643484/how-do-i-get-rid-of-annoying-message-on-output-log-pwc4011-servletrequest-getr/